# How does C++ know which function to call to compute a given expression?

Tags: c++

Typically, a standard function is called by
`functionName(list of arguments)`.
Another standard way to call a function of an object is
`object.functionName(list of arguments)`.
Both methods are clear and easy to understand since the function signatures are called in the exact order.

However, when it comes to the below:

- A unary operator overloading: `classA::operator-()`, for example, doesn't take any argument. So when we write `object2 = -object1`,assuming `object2` and `object1` are both instances of `classA`, how does C++ know that it has to call `classA::operator-()` since we didn't write `object2 = object1.operator-()`?
- A global function that defines the + operation between 2 objects for example `Complex operator+(int number, const Complex& c)`. So when we write `answer = 10 + aComplexNumber`, how does C++ know which function to call since we didn't write `operator+(10, aComplexNumber)`?
- A `classA::operator[]` operator overloading: so when we call `object[argument]`. How does C++ know which function to call since we didn't write `object.operator[](argument)`?

Edit: thank you all for the suggestions. I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: In the case of `-object1`, I suspect the argument is the magic `this`, but I can't say I've ever tried it. And now I have. Looks like it compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/MaPKe4z99

Comment: It is basically a hold over from C roots, see [C11 Standard - 6.5.3.3(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.3) "*The result of the unary `-` operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand.*" For C++ that is [expr.unary.op - 7.6.2.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#op-7)

Comment: The C++ cite is [\[expr.unary.op\] - 7.6.2.2(p8)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#op-8) - the link above was to (p7) off by 1.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, as I think no comment or answer really answers the question, which imho is clear enough. I would probably rephrase it as "How does C++ know which function to call in order to compute a given expression? E.g. how does it know that `++X` requires calling `TheClassOfX::operator++()`?"

Comment: The compiler just parses the expression and is able to decide on which kind operation is needed. For `object2 = -object1;` the compiler knows it has to assing the result of the unary minus on `object1` to `object2`. For the unary minus it considers the alternatives of how this operation can be implemented and once it has figured out this, it considers the available assignment operations. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators for the alternatives considered.

Comment: Hi all, I have edited my question. Hopefully, it's clearer now.

Comment: @Khanh, the answer is in fabian's comment. If that doesn't answer your question, then edit it once more.

Comment: @Enlico. Thanks. So, in short, when the compiler reads an expression, it considers various alternatives to understand the expression and chooses the best one at the end? And the 3 examples above are common ways the compiler interprets expressions?

Comment: @Khanh, I'm not expert of parsing, but don't confuse it with other scenarii where a "disambiguation" is necessary. E.g., given `int f(int);` and `int f(double);`, a call to `f(2)` will require overload resolution to decide which `f` to call, but that happens during compilation, and has nothing to do with recognizing that, say `++i` will call `typeofi::operator++()` and `i++` will call `typeofi::operator++(int unuseddummy)`.

Comment: @Enlico thank you. I understand your point. Let me see if I can edit my question once more so that hopefully it may help other people :)

Answer (score -2):

This all depends on the operator.

`Class::operator- ()` only operates on one item, so therefore, it does not need an argument since it can just be a member overloaded operator. (i.e. `this` will be operated on). This unary operator's return type should be the same as the object:

```
Class obj1;
obj1 = -obj1; //Calls the unary operator- and then the operator=
```

Now, let's suppose you want to implement the operator again but have it do operations on 2 Objects. That's where we add two different arguments and make it a non-member overloaded operator. For example: `operator-(const Class & lhs, const Class & rhs)`, this will also most likely return an `Class` and will be called when you create two `Class` and subtract one from the other:

```
Class obj1;
Class obj2;
Class obj3 = obj1 - obj2; //Calls the non-member operator then operator=
```

Some overloaded operators must be member overloaded operators, such as the assignment `operator= (const Object & rhs)` and by default, the left-hand-side is `this` since you are assigning `this` Object to the `rhs`.

So again, it depends on the operator. You'll have to be more specific if you want more details on a specific operator.

Comment: I think you may have grabbed a different unary operator.  Feel free to pull from my comments above if you want to add to or update your answer. I'm not going to write it up.

Comment: The unary minus operator can be implemented at namespace scope and in this case the binary minus operator could be implemented as member: `Class operator-(Class const&); Class Class::operator-(Class const&) const;` Also, if the resturn type is `Class`, the move assignment operator is preferred and in case of `Class obj3 = obj1 - obj2;` the move or copy constructor would be used instead of the assignment operator and even that doesn't happen here because of  mandatory copy elision. You need to create the object separately for your claim to be true `Class obj3; obj3 = obj1 - obj2;`